# Wordpress - failed to write to disk MOV file

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress blog can upload image files fine.
However, when trying to upload an MOV file, after 100%, it says "failed to write to disk".

What caused that and how can I fix that?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.

I'm running out of disk space that's why.